# Javascript - Drag´n´Drop Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At first here is my Fiddle:

So maybe it won´t work on Fiddle because the window size is too small.
Here are the problems I have and I can´t solve after trying it for 8 days -.- .
1.Deactivate Drag option after once dropped:
So once an item was dropped it shouldn´t be draggable anymore , so how is it possible to do this?
2.I can´t drop my items in the e.g. 6. or 7. row.
3.Everytime I try to add instead of a text in the header an image it won´t appear.
4.Also my footer doesn´t appear.

I hope someone can help me please,
And sorry for my bad english :|
Greetz

Comment: Nothing found on your Fiddle Link. Please check it. I think, your link is broken. Half of text is linked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lf1vvjjb/ I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

this example is the in w3school so i have to find and gives you try this one it is work i try also

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</body>
</html>
```